О возможной ошибке в правиле Розенталя (обособление приложений)
Рассмотрим предложение:
Среди актёров передвижной труппы Сергея Эйзенштейна были юноши, впоследствии ставшие известными кинорежиссёрами, — Григорий Александров, Иван Пырьев, а также актёр Максим Штраух (Газ.);
Можно предположить, что запятая перед первым тире не нужна:
Среди актёров передвижной труппы Сергея Эйзенштейна были юноши, впоследствии ставшие известными кинорежиссёрами — Григорий Александров, Иван Пырьев, а также актёр Максим Штраух (Газ.);
Кинорежиссерами стали только двое, а третьим указан актер. Тогда второе тире опущено перед запятой (запятая перед союзом А), что соответствует правилу, а запятой перед первым тире не должно быть.
 Примечание. Одно тире (первое или второе) 
 опускается:если по условиям контекста после 
 обособленного приложения ставится запятая: Если бы 
 он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор — весы, 
 то понял бы источник ошибки; Используя специальное 
 устройство для дыхания человека под водой — 
 акваланг, можно погружаться на глубину в десятки 
 метров; Среди актёров передвижной труппы Сергея 
 Эйзенштейна были юноши, впоследствии ставшие 
 известными кинорежиссёрами, — Григорий 
 Александров, Иван Пырьев, а также актёр Максим 
 Штраух (Газ.);


Пояснения? Все трое стали режиссерами? //  А какое отношение пример имеет к правилу пункта 10, примечание (пункт 1), где говорится о том, что второе тире опускается?  // У меня бумажная книга, двухтомник 2005 года. Там вс в точности так, как в правилах Справочника.  // У меня всегда это предложение вызывало сомнение, думала,чо оно здесь не по теме. А сейчас пригляделась и думаю, что запятая перед первым тире не нужна.  Тогда все нормально, второе тире опущено.

Среди юнош был и актер,  ставший режиссером.

Может, и был, я не знаю. Но тогда предложение не имеет смысла, а также что этот пример делает в этой теме?  Где опущенное второе тире? Пусть лингвисты разберутся наконец)

Шарон, здесь запятая перед тире закрывает обособленное определение, а тире используется для выделения уточняющей конструкции, в то время как в приведенных вами примерах тире обособляет приложение, после чего предложение продолжается (например, главной или придаточной частью). Это разные синтаксические структуры, в данном (выше) предложении запятая перед тире обязательна, это никоим образом не ошибка.

Это ответ лингвистов омского института.

В общем, Серж, я недовольна ответами лингвистов из Омска, они не понимают вопроса. Пусть почитают текст правила. Там говорится, что для обособления приложений может использоваться тире, но в ряде случаев одно тире опускается. Случаи перечислены в примечаниях - всего 9 случаев, везде одно тире. Но в этом предложении ничего не опущено, там и так одно тире. Что этот пример делает тогда  в "примечаниях"? Вы сами-то меня понимает? // А вот если отделить актера от списка, тогда понятно, что делает.  // Короче, надо или убрать запятую, или убрать пример из "примечания", пункт 1).

Второй ответ. Да, теперь понятно :) Нет, не ошибка, синтаксические структуры все-таки разные: в предложении про актеров перед обособленным с помощью тире приложением стоит еще обособленное согласованное определение - так вот, запятая перед тире закрывает первое обособление, а тире отделяет второе.
Пожалуйста :)

Серж, вы хорошо видите тире в этом предложении? В нем обычная независимое постановка запятой, закрывающей согласованное определение и обособленного с помощью тире ряда приложений в конце предложения. Все по правилам. // Поместите, пожалуйста, это  предложение в пункт 10 (2).  Это можно сделать или нет? // Где там можно было изначально поставить два тире, о потом опустить одно? Вы мне про это расскажите, и я буду довольна. Запишите исходное предложение с двумя тире.

А вот моя исходная запись с двумя тире : Среди актёров передвижной труппы Сергея Эйзенштейна были юноши, впоследствии ставшие
известными кинорежиссёрами, — Григорий
Александров, Иван Пырьев, — а также актёр Максим
Штраух. // И вот второе тире убираем. // Кстати, этот Штраух стал впоследствии театральным режиссером, а не кинорежиссером. Хотя бы факты проверьте, какой он фильм снял?
